# cannot get input value of Struts 2 file selector with Angular

Tags: angularjs, jsp, struts2

I am using Angular and I want to get access to the file input field's file name attributes and display it in another input box.

This is the file upload field:

```
<div class="btn btn-orange btn-file col-sm-3" >
     <s:text name="expedientes.btn.seleccionar.fichero" /> 
     <s:file name="form.filesUpload" multiple="multiple" ng-model="filesUploadModel" id="filesUploadId"/>
</div>
```

And the input box to show file name:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"         
      id="fileNameId"               name="fileName"                          
      ng-model="fileNameModel"      ng-disabled="true"                       
      ng-init=""                    ng-bind="fileNameModel = filesUploadModel">
```

But the `ng-bind` is not working.

I also tried to define `$watch` for the file input field like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
            $scope.files = angular.element(document.querySelector('#filesUploadId'));
            return files;
            },
              function(newValue, oldValue) {
            $("#fileNameId").val(files.files[0].name);
            });
```

to watch if the `<input type="file" id="filesUploadId">` has changed, select this element and return it as `files`, and let the element with id `fileNameId`'s value equals to `files.files[0].name`, because the file upload input has an attribute named `files` with all the files I upload, and their file names `files[i].name`.

But FF tells me `files is undefined` and no avail. It's not working.

Am I doing something wrong here? Please help and thanks!!

Edit: I am using this and no error, but no result either:

```
if (!angular.equals(document.getElementById("filesUploadId"), null)) {
$scope.$watch(function() {
           var myFiles  = document.getElementById("filesUploadId");
            return myFiles;
            },
              function(newValue, oldValue) {
            $( "#fileNameId" ).val(function(){
                var result = null;
                $(myFiles).each(function(){
                    result = name + this.attr(files).attr(name);
                });
                return result;
                    });
               });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with pure JavaScript, enlighted by another question here:
[AngularJs: How to check for changes in file input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields)

Actually, I find it impossible to use `onchange()` when the function I want to call is wrapped in angular module, except in the way in above answer:

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFileName()"
```

And in my script I only use pure JavaScript, except for the definition of the function:

```
angular.module('es.redfinanciera.app').controller('PanelMandarCorreoCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

....(other functions)

$scope.setFileName = function() {
    var result = "";
       var adjuntos = document.getElementById("filesUploadId").files;
       for (i = 0; i < adjuntos.length; i++){
           result = result + adjuntos[i].name + "\r\n";
           };
    document.getElementById("fileNameId").value = result;
}

}
$scope.btnClean = function() {
    document.getElementById("filesUploadId").value = "";
    document.getElementById("fileNameId").value = "";
};
```

And in my jsp page, finally I have my file upload button and a clean button like this:

```
<div class="btn btn-orange btn-file col-sm-3" >
    <s:text name="expedientes.btn.seleccionar.fichero" /> 
    <s:file name="correoForm.filesUpload" id="filesUploadId" multiple="multiple" ng-model="filesUploadModel" 
            onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFileName()"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-normal" type="button"     ng-click="btnClean()">
        <s:text name="expedientes.btn.quitar.fichero" />
    </button>
</div>
```

I have a `<textarea>` to display all the file names:

```
<textarea class="form-control"   ng-model="fileNameModel"
          name="fileName"        id="fileNameId"
          ng-disabled="true"></textarea>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
Clear button is not working in IE8 because it is not permitted in IE8 to set `""` value to a file input field. My guess is, I can remove this file input field and copy a new one, with same style but no file is selected. But I have found a good question who has amounts of answers here:

[clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery/13351234#13351234)

Also, I heard that in IE8 `onchange()` event will not be triggered if you only select a file, you must add `this.blur()` after selecting a file. Regarding this issue, IE is following strictly the spec, but FF is not. But in my case, the event is actually triggered. Maybe because I am testing under IE 11 using Developing Tools' emulator for IE8.