# Angularjs : How to check for the value changes in file input fields?

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="file"  accept="image/*" ng-model="imageupload" />
```

My problem is, I want to call a function when the user will browse an image file then a function will trigger.

The value of the ng-model of the input type file is going to change. Then a function will call, that function will upload the image to a folder.

That has to implement in AngularJS

Comment: I can't understand the question bro, can you give me more explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs: How to check for changes in file input fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields)

Answer (score 2):

You should look at `ng-change` directive of input field

> **[ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)**
>
> Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input.

Example

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input ng-model='imageUri' type='text' ng-change='alert()'/>
</body>
```

Angular code:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.alert = function(){
      alert('hello');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider u have a html element with type as file,now add an ng-change directive to that element.

```
<input type="file" ng-change="trigger()">
```

Now in your js refer the code as below

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.trigger=function(){
//your code to copy a file to folder
}
});
```