# angular scope changes with file input type

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a preview method as follows

```
<span class="error-message">{{FilesNotSelected}}</span>

<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().previewFile('firstLevel')">
```

In my script I am changing a scope variable as follows

```
 $scope.previewFile = function (uploadType) {
      $scope.FilesNotSelected = "Selected";
 }
```

I am unable to get the changed value to be displayed in the UI.
Can someone please help me find the issues. It seems scope get changed.

Comment: try this   <input type="file" ng-change="previewFile('firstLevel')">

Comment: @hadiJZ  in that case previewFile method is not being called.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields

Comment: Thanks @hadiJZ it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with scope. Somehow the scope get changed and the updated value is not available.  `$scope.$apply(function (scope){})`  helped solve this issue.

```
$scope.previewFile = function (uploadType) {
    $scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                      .
                      .
                      .
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            $scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                scope.FilesNotSelected = false;
                      .
                      .
                      .
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```