# AngularJs Upload Button Function

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make upload button on my page using angularjs and bootstrap, But i have problem to give (upload) function on that button in angularjs. The button should upload a text file from pc to browser. Can anyone help me? here is HTML code...

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-2">
      <button type="button" class="nav-justified btn btn-primary upload-button"> Upload </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're code isn't showing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs: How to check for changes in file input fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields)

Comment: you have to use `<input type="file"></input>` to upload file

Comment: Thanks i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out this Lightweight Angular directive to upload files.

[ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

You can checkout working demo/code here

[ng-file-upload wokring deom/code](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/)

```js
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
      data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
    });

    file.upload.then(function (response) {
      $timeout(function () {
        file.result = response.data;
      });
    }, function (response) {
      if (response.status > 0)
        $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function (evt) {
      // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
      file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    });
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Upload on form submit</legend>
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="username" size="31" required>
      <i ng-show="myForm.userName.$error.required">*required</i>
      <br>Photo:
      <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file"    
             accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required
             ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
      <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i><br>
      <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large 
          {{errorFile.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 2M</i>
      <img ng-show="myForm.file.$valid" ngf-thumbnail="picFile" class="thumb"> <button ng-click="picFile = null" ng-show="picFile">Remove</button>
      <br>
      <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" 
              ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button>
      <span class="progress" ng-show="picFile.progress >= 0">
        <div style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%" 
            ng-bind="picFile.progress + '%'"></div>
      </span>
      <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
      <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
  </form>
</body>
```