# Angular: Looking for an explanation on custom directive syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I copied a custom directive that [watches for changes on form file inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields).

```
angular.module('customDirective', [])
.directive('ngFileInputChange', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.ngFileInputChange);
            element.bind('change', onChangeHandler);
        }
    };
});
```

Then I use it in the template like so:

```
<input ng-model="vm.image" ng-file-input-change="vm.base64Test" ...>
```

And this works fine.

However, this doesn't work:

```
<input ng-model="vm.image" ng-file-input-change="vm.base64Test()" ...>
```

Note the `()` at the end of `base64Test()`. With a generic `ng-click`, the parenthesis are fine, or even required (how else would I pass arguments to the function?) but with the custom directive, parenthesis cause an error.

I only have a vague understanding of what `scope.$eval(attrs.ngFileInputChange)` is actually doing, so maybe I could make some change in that?

EDIT:

I should also add that I need access to some scope variables. For example, if I didn't have to use the custom directive, I would write something like this in my controller:

```
vm.base64Test(associatedData){
    console.log(associatedData);    
}
```

And then:

```
<input ng-change("vm.base64Test(vm.associatedData)">
```

But ng-change doesn't watch file input contents and the custom directive doesn't allow arguments (other than event), so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you're planning on calling a method from a directive's *API* (so to speak), you need to identify it as a callback:

```
scope: {
    'onChange': '&ngFileInputChange'
}
```

This simply means you're defined/exposing a way to declare a callback when the `scope.onChange` gets triggered. It also means you don't need to `$parse` or `$eval` since the isolate scope can handle that for you.

Next you can trigger that callback much like you're already doing:

```
element.bind('change', function(evt){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        var payload = { $data:<whatever-you-pull-from-your-file-change-evt> }
        $scope.onChange(payload)
    }) 
});
```

One thing to note is that I'm calling the callback within the `$scope.$apply`.  Because you're listening on non-angular events (e.g. onChange), you need to notify angular a change has occurred outside of the `$digest` cycle.

Where you've declared your directive, in your actual callback (probably defined on your view controller) you can pass the payload to the method like so:

```
<input ng-file-input-change="vm.doSomething($data)">
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing a function to a directive you usually need to pass the function pointer, so the directive can call the function later with arbitrary arguments.

In this case, your directive is evaluating the attribute to a function pointer (that's what the $eval is doing), and then binding it as a `change` handler to the element the directive is attached to.  You don't need (or want) to have parenthesis.

There's nothing wrong with your code as it is currently.  I have a directive which does the exact same thing, it works great!  (and when your function `vm.base64Test` is called you will get the [standard arguments for a change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) on an input.)  So you can have `vm.base64Test` be:

```
function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  // your other code here
  // event.target will give you the input element the code was called on
  // event.target.files will give you an array of the files selected by the user
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I essentially did what you have here, but I'm still running into problems. I expanded my question to explain.

Comment: where are you defining vm.base64test?  It sounds like an architecture issue to me, you should define the fileChange event handling function in the context of a controller that has access to the $scope where the directive is used so you can access the functions that way.  I can make a plunkr if this is not clear.