# how to send request from action form to angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest

im using this code to upload file to my REST API, and it works fine ,
this is my form :

```
<form action="webresources/documents/upload" 
      method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p>
        Select a file : 
        <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

</form>
```

and this is my REST API :

```
@POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(@MultipartForm Document document) {
.....
}
```

my question is: how to send the same request using angularjs instead of using 
**action="webresources/documents/upload"** on my form.

Comment: This code has nothing related to angular. As such, I would like to remind you that SO is not here to write code for you. Do some research, write some angular code, and come back to us when you have a specific problem.

Comment: I think he's asking how to upload a file using AngularJS. It's not completely irrelevant.

Comment: Hi @Michael Markidis , thank you for your response, if you read my question , you will find it clear and i have a specific  issue , i'm asking on how i can upload my file using angular , without calling my REST API in the form action ="" , but please try to understand people before attacking them,regards

Answer (score 0):

You don't require a **form** tag,

This is how your HTML would look like,

```
 <p>
        Select a file : 
        <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
    </p>
<button ng-click="upload()">Upload</button>
```

Your controller code would be something like this,

```
$scope.upload = function () {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', file);

  $http({
    url: 'webresources/documents/upload',
    data: fd,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": undefined
    }
  });
}
```

This will upload your file to the server without **form** tags.

Comment: Hi @Kensplanet, thank you for the response , but i got an error "ReferenceError: file is not defined" , please where is the declaration of variable file?

Comment: You will have to implement the logic as per this Stackoverflow answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields