# Call a function from input's onchange

Tags: angularjs

I'm using controller as syntax.

And when my file input changed, i want to trigger a function.

how to do that?

below is my code with $scope syntax

```
<input class="upload" type="file" accept="image/*" ng-model="image"
                onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this)">
```

Comment: Why not use `ng-change="yourController.yourFunction()"`  ?

Comment: if type="file" ,ng-change can't be used.

Answer (score 6):

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields), you could use a custom directive to listen for changes in your input file.

view.html:

```
<input type="file" custom-on-change="uploadFile">
```

controller.js:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.uploadFile = function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;
    };
});
```

directive.js:

```
app.directive('customOnChange', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.customOnChange);
      element.bind('change', onChangeHandler);
    }
  };
});
```

[View JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sqren/27ugfym6/)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ng-change="nameOfFunction()"` this will trigger when this input change

Or use [HERE](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

Comment: I dont think `ng-change` works in `<input type="file">` according to this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375 (I didnt test...). However `angular-file-upload` is indeed a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use angular `scope.$watch`. In your controller, add this:

```
scope.$watch("image", function(newValue, oldValue) {
   // Do anything you want here
   scope.uploadImage(newValue);
}
```

More information about `scope.$watch`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope