# Javascript . Uncaught ReferenceError: OnChange is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select name="Connection" id="dropConnection"  ng-change="connectionChange(this)" ></select>
```

following is the script.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    function connectionChange(sel)
      {
        var connectionName = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
        alert("connectionName");
      }
});
```

Dropdown contents are added from json respose and its all working fine. The error is :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: OnChange is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange
```

Comment: change to `ng-change`

Comment: tried. but not working

Comment: Use custom directive of onChange https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966899/call-a-function-from-inputs-onchange

Comment: use custom directive for that like use in this example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966899/call-a-function-from-inputs-onchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `onchange` but `ng-change`. See for more here [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). And remove your inner function

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var connectionName = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    alert("connectionName");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the function in $scope like this

```
 $scope.connectionChange = function (sel){
    var connectionName = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    alert("connectionName");
  }
```

also use `ng-change` for your html