# onchange would not change $scope in AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, angularjs-scope

I have the following code (see below). When I click on the button and select the file, data.myVar in the view remains unchanged. (Somehow I do see that `$scope.data.myVar` updates correctly while stepping through the controller). Why is this happening?

html excerpt (it is under under the controller below):

```
{{data.myVar}}

<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setRuleFile(this)" />
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.data = {
        myVar: 'init'
    };

    $scope.setRuleFile = function(element) {
        $scope.data.myVar = 'changed';
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Well, it should work.. any errors in console? You could provide a simple demo that reproduces this.

Comment: event is outside angular context so you need to tell angular to run digest

Comment: @charlietfl: this is just an excerpt from html file which is view template, didn't want to paste all the routing, etc. Thought I am missing some simple fact about onchange or "file" type.

Comment: use `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: @charlietfl: Still do not get it: which event is outside angular context?$scope.$apply() actually fixed the issue, thanks for that!

Comment: angular is not aware of `onchange` ... so if you modify scope use `$apply` so angular knows to run digest.. try `$scope.data.myVar = 'changed';$scope.$apply()`

Comment: @charlietfl, is correct. Check it: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qv8cDpUPD5OL1VXTRpKX?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

It is less hacky to use a directive instead. Here is a similar question:
[AngularJs: How to check for changes in file input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields/19647381#19647381)

Comment: Although I found that Angular does not allow me to pass element from directive into callback that I define in the scope: Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: - so it did not work for me.