# Angular 1.5 ES6 Input File Change Handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, ecmascript-6

I have an input file upload in a modal and I'm trying to handle its onChange event. I created a directive for the custom onChange handler for input file upload by following this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19647381/769326

This is my code in ES6:

```
class FileUploadOnChange {
  constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'A';
  }

  link(scope, element, attrs) {
    const onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.fileUploadOnChange);
    element.bind('change', onChangeHandler);
  }

  static directiveFactory() {
    FileUploadOnChange.instance = new FileUploadOnChange();
    return FileUploadOnChange.instance;
  }
}

class MyController {
  constructor() {
    this.test = 'Hello, World';
  }

  doSomething(e) {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .directive('fileUploadOnChange', FileUploadOnChange.directiveFactory)
  .component('myFileUpload', {
    template: '<input type="file" file-upload-on-change="$ctrl.doSomething">',
    controller: MyController
  });
```

However, when I select a file, the value of `this` when I log it in `doSomething` is the input element and not the controller. How do I pass the controller context to the changeHandler? Thank you.

Also, here's a [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXyRrB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I basically did what was in the SO link in my question but added a `getScope` function to, well, get the scope you're looking for. It's a simple recursive function to return the scope with your controller alias:

```
function getScope(scope, controllerAlias) {
  if (controllerAlias in scope) {
    return scope[controllerAlias];
  } else {
    getScope(scope.$parent, controllerAlias);
  }
}
```

So in the [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjAqzK?editors=1011), you just have to call `getScope` and pass `this` and your controller alias, which by default is `$ctrl`.

```
const scope = getScope(this, '$ctrl');
```