# Getting value input file is empty

Tags: javascript, html, angular, file-upload

This is my little problem, when i'm trying to get the value from my input of type="file".

this is how i'm doing:

```
<tr ng-repeat="imagenDatos in tableImagenesPunto | filter: busquedaDatosPunto " >
  <td>PNG</td>
  <td>{{imagenDatos.id_puntoEmpresa}}</td>
  <td>{{imagenDatos.nombre_punto}}</td>
  <td>{{imagenDatos.direccion_punto}}</td>
  <td>
   <input type="file" name="uploadFile[]" id="inputFileServer" accept="image/png" ng-click="inputChange()" />
  </td>
  <td>{{imagenDatos.ruta_punto}}</td>
  <td>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm "  value="Upload3" ng-click="uploadFile()" id="btnSubirArchivo" role="button" data-original-title="Subir Logo">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   </button>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

And this is on the JS

```
$scope.uploadFile = function()
{
 var file = document.getElementById('inputFileServer').files[0];
 console.log(file);
}
```

The results is "undefined", how can i know what is wrong with that?

Comment: well when do you call your code?

Comment: Have you selected a file with the file input? What value do you expect to be displayed in the console?

Comment: @quentin yes, i've selected the file, but it takes as"no selected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably reading the `files` before the user has uploaded a file. Try validating `files.length` before accessing `files[0]`. That would prevent the error.

In the snippet below, I have set a `setInterval` that prints the count of files every one second. You can see that once the user uploads the file, the count will be updated.

In your application, you can listen to the `change` event on the input, and then based on file length validation, you can access it.

```js
var files = document.getElementById('inputFileServer').files;

setInterval(function() {
  files = document.getElementById('inputFileServer').files;
  console.log("Number of files: ", files.length);
}, 1000);

function inputChange() {
  alert("Input changes");
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="inputFileServer" accept="image/png" onchange="inputChange()" />
```

Comment: @epascarello I thought of showing the file length validation. Also, I just added the change event so that they can read the files once the file is selected. Anything else you can think of?

Comment: The result is Number of files:  0,

Comment: @jecorrales Yes, so when the number of files is zero, it means no file has been uploaded yet. But when you upload a file, it will give you the count 1. Meaning, once that count is greater than zero, you can access the first file like `files[0]`.

Comment: I've updated my question, and i'm getting that result, something is wrong, it takes like the file is not selected.

Comment: `ng-click` is triggered when the user clicks on the input to select a file. So your code is executed by the time user selects the file. You should be using the `onchange` event. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17923521/5894241) for more details.