# On file reader's call back change corresponding input elements scope's property?

Tags: web-applications, angularjs

With reference to question [File pick with Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631702/file-pick-with-angular-js), on file reader's on load i want to modify a parent scope's property. Consider

```
$scope.fileLoaded = false; //initially
$scope.file_changed = function(element, $scope) {

 $scope.$apply(function(scope) {
     var photofile = element.files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e) {
        $scope.fileLoaded = true;  // I intend to do!
        ...
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(photofile);
 });
```

});

How do i achieve this for HTML:

```
<input ng-model="photo"
   onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)"
   type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

It fails every time with error Cannot set property 'fileLoaded' of undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.

1. use `ng-change` instead of onchange.
2. do this in a directive. You don't want to be accessing elements in your controller. You can two-way bind the fileLoaded in your directive so you can access it in your controller if you'd really like to, or you can encapsulate all your functionality into a nice directive.

I wrote a sort-of-similar directive awhile back, you can check it out here: https://github.com/jrowny/SpriteHero/blob/master/js/directives/file.js I wrote that before I really knew angular that well so it could be a little messy. Also, it doesn't use the filefield directly, just invoked from a random link.

Angular is really a mess if you don't master directives pretty early on. Otherwise it's like you've got a ladder with only a few rungs provided.

Comment: Cannot use ng-change for input type file. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375