# AngularJs - file selector in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am happily using the file selector from solution @Snowman's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631702/file-pick-with-angular-js/)

Now, however, I want to use it in an `ng-repeat` loop, and am stuck.

I take the liberty of copying the solution from that question:

```
angular
  .module('app.services')
  .directive('fileChange', function() {
    return {
     restrict: 'A',
     scope: {
       handler: '&'
     },
     link: function (scope, element) {
      element.on('change', function (event) {
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.handler({files: event.target.files});
        });
      });
     }
    };
});

<input type="file" file-change handler="fileSelect(files)">

$scope.fileSelect = function(files) {
  var file = files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    console.log("on load", e.target.result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

How do I indicate to the `$scope.fileSelect()` function which photo has just had its file selected?

---

[Update] Aargh! I just realized that I did not make the question clear enough. 
I need the file name, ***and*** some other data from the repeat. Let's say that I want a file name ***and*** a description of the image, entered by the user.

So, I have declared

```
$scope.image = {'fileName' : '',
                'description' : ''};

$scope.images = [];   // array of $scope.image
```

And, in the HTML, in the `ng-repeat`,  I will have (pseudo code only)

```
<ng-repeat image in images>
   <input type="text" ng-model="image.description"/>
   <input type="file" file-change handler="fileSelect(files)">
```

It's the last `<input>` that I don't know how to code. Ideally, I want to pass the `image` object to the `file-change handler` function.

How can I do that?

---

[Final update] just in case anyone every reads this & finds it interesting.

```
<ng-repeat image in images>
   <input type="text" ng-model="image.description"/>
   <input type="file" file-change handler="fileSelect(image , files)">
```

added a `image` parameter, and also to `$scope.fileSelect(image , files)` in the controller. Note that ***no change*** was required on the directive.

Works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried right here with a few differences and it's working. The only thing I've changed was the controller that I added to test.

Check how I did it: (click on Run code snippet to see it in action)

```js
angular
  .module('app.services', [])
  .controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.inputs = [1,2,3,4];
    
    $scope.fileSelect = function(files) {
      var file = files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("on load", e.target.result);
      }
      
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
  })
  .directive('fileChange', function() {
    return {
     restrict: 'A',
     scope: {
       handler: '&'
     },
     link: function (scope, element) {
      element.on('change', function (event) {
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.handler({files: event.target.files});
        });
      });
     }
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular test</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app.services">

<div ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
  <input type="file" 
         file-change 
         handler="fileSelect(files)"
         ng-repeat="input in inputs">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Just a quick note: depending on your machine, the console.log command that you are running can go pretty slow (because it's logging the content of the file)**

Comment: It is not often that I see such a god and detailed answer from a  new guy (welcome aboard), so I will award a 100 point bonus. Thanks. It certainly works just fine, so I will figure how to adapt it to my code.

Comment: Aargh! I just realized that I did not make the question clear enough. Please see update. If it is easy, please let know; otherwise, I will post a new, clearer question. My apologies, and I will still give you the bonus in 2 days, when the system permits it

Comment: I got it, thanks to your help. I updated the question to give the answer. Expect your bounty in 2 days time :-)

Comment: Cool! I'm happy that I could help you, @Mawg! And thanks for the welcoming! I've been an avid reader of Stack Overflow, but I've never signed up. I thought that it would be cool to help some people here, as Stack Overflow helped me A LOT in the last years.

Comment: If you are going to give great help like that, then you will be a great asset to the community :-)